# Does the delegate property have any special meaning?

Tags: objective-c

In many resources I often see a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SomethingDelegate> delegate;
```

does the **name** delegate have a special meaning?

Whats the difference in just storing a

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SomethingDelegate> somethingDelegate;
```

reference and calling `somethingDelegate`'s methods instead of using the `delegate` object?

Comment: `delegate` is the name of the property.

Comment: Well, that's not my question

Comment: It does not have a specific meaning. However, when subclassing, you can have multiple delegates, therefore using only the name `delegate` can be problematic and misleading. For example, `UITableView` has two delegates and it subclasses `UIScrollView` which already has a property `delegate`. Therefore you have `delegate` and `dataSource`, which are both delegates. Also note that in most situations it's better to use a callback closure than a delegate. Delegate is better when there is a complicated interactions between two classes, with multiple methods.

Comment: `delegate` is just the name of the property, while `id <SomethingDelegate>` is the protocol that provides the delegate methods.  You don't call the delegate methods directly, the object uses them to perform customization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `delegate` is not special. Calling it `beMyDelegate` would not change its functionality in any way. It's no different than naming any other property. You simply give it a name that makes sense for what it represents. But the name you choose has no impact on what it does or how it works.

Comment: thanks. I was confused since multiple classes in frameworks have a `delegate` property without a special name so I concluded that delegate is something special and/or declared in NSObject with a special behaviour

Comment: @Raildex The use of `delegate` is common because it is clear and understood. Normally there is no need for `somethingDelegate` when a simple `delegate` is sufficient.